# Retaining search results after submitting the search (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, select, submit

I'd like to make it so that after users submit their search, the option they selected stays selected upon the search form's reload. Here's my code for one of these select boxes:

```
    <div><%= f.select :tod_like, Course.tod_array, {:include_blank => true, :selected => params[:search][:tod_like], :class=>"float_and_margin"} %></div>
```

The key code is the

```
:selected => params[:search][:tod_like]
```

When I refresh my page, I get the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

I know I'm getting this error because there's params[:search][:tod_like] is blank. How do I set :selected so that it's blank if the user has not submitted a form, but is the submission, otherwise? I tried using a ternary operator, but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: usually, I use hidden fields to keep search options within the view. Helpful with will_paginate as well

Answer (score 0):

Is the params key correct?

I take it the form f is for an instance of Course so wouldn't it be something like

`@course.tod_like = params[:search][:tod_like] ? params[:search][:tod_like] : ""`

at the top of the function that generates the search function (you have mentioned that you've tried a ternary statement but did you replace the :selected option at the same time?

Then :selected => @course.tod_like in the select tag?

```
<div><%= f.select :tod_like, Course.tod_array, {:include_blank => true, :selected => @course.tod_like, :class=>"float_and_margin"} %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I ended up fixing this problem by defining a ternary operator in my courses controller, and then passing this instance variable into the appropriate view.

```
@tod_results = params[:search] == nil ? :blank : params[:search][:tod_like]

<div><%= f.select :tod_like, Course.tod_array, {:include_blank => true, :selected => @tod_results, :class=>"float_and_margin"} %></div>
```

The key difference between this code and the previous ternary operator I tried is that I'm testing to see if params[:search] is nil, not if params[:search][:tod_like] is nil. Since params[:search] is already nil, I got the "you were expecting an array, but got nil" error when I tried to use params[:search][:tod_like].

Thanks for your responses!